# Could close get requests removed if user making request does not read subsequent edits?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen, on-hold

I have a very important question that could use a helpful answer.

It was put on hold (I see and agree with the reasoning for the hold), but have long since fixed the issues and complaints raised with my question and would really like it to be opened for a real response.

I feel that unresponsible users who make issue close requests but do not check up on edits made to the original question should have their requests withdrawn after an arbitrary amount of time.

If this is already a feature, please excuse my ignorance, but I did read through a great deal of rules when registering for S.O. and cannot recall such a rule.  Why?

If the question truly is horse excrement, then the question will likely get enough close requests to be killed anyways, even if the requests were automatically removed after a set number of hours.

*If the aforementioned feature truly doesn't exist, then why the heck not?*

([Original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647850/edit-difficulties-with-fstream-reading-from-text-file-to-a-c-string) that made me feel this way)

Comment: I don't see it is put on-hold anymore? Someone has reopened your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closed questions that get reopen votes already go into a [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) so that the community can vote to reopen them.

Strictly speaking, it's not the close voters' responsibility to reopen rehabilitated questions; it is the community's responsibility.  Question askers also have a responsibility to post questions *(on the first try)* that will pass muster with the community.  It's not reasonable to ask close voters to actively monitor questions to see if the OP will rehabilitate them.

Your question already got 4 reopen votes, so I cast the fifth one.

**Some additional observations:**

1. Do not put monikers like "EDIT:" in either the title or body of your questions.  Every post on the Stack Exchange network already has a detailed edit history that anyone can review.
2. Do not put pleas for reopening questions or other meta content in the body of your questions.  Use comments for such content.  The question body is for the question only.

Good luck.